# How to join these Django models?

Tags: django, django-models

How should I join these Django models to get all Player models that participate in challenges of logged in users (see variable named challenges_participants in views.py ? I did not came up with a solution on how to efficiently implement this with Django models. Thanks a lot!

Example data:
Let's assume John is logged in. As we can see in PlayerChallenge model he is part of challenge 1 and 2. What I am trying to do is to get all player objects that are part of challenge 1 (Roger is this example) and a second list for all player objects that are part of challenge 2 (Roger and Claude in this example).

Player model

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦════════════════╗
║ user_name ║ user_id ║ wallet_balance ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬════════════════╣
║ John      ║     123 ║             20 ║
║ Roger     ║     231 ║             15 ║
║ Claude    ║     582 ║             10 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩════════════════╝
```

Challenge model

```
╔════╦═════════╦══════╦════════╦═══════════════════╦══════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ id ║ status  ║ type ║ amount ║ created_timestamp ║ duration ║ started_timestamp ║ end_timestamp ║
╠════╬═════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║  1 ║ active  ║    1 ║     20 ║ TimeStamp         ║ 02:00:00 ║ TimeStamp         ║ TimeStamp     ║
║  2 ║ waiting ║    2 ║     30 ║ TimeStamp         ║ 04:00:00 ║ TimeStamp         ║ TimeStamp     ║
║  3 ║ waiting ║    1 ║     35 ║ TimeStamp         ║ 07:00:00 ║ TimeStamp         ║ TimeStamp     ║
╚════╩═════════╩══════╩════════╩═══════════════════╩══════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

PlayerChallenge model

```
╔════╦════════╦═══════════╦════════════════════╗
║ id ║ player ║ challenge ║ accepted_timestamp ║
╠════╬════════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ John   ║         1 ║ TimeStamp          ║
║  2 ║ Roger  ║         1 ║ TimeStamp          ║
║  3 ║ Roger  ║         2 ║ TimeStamp          ║
║  4 ║ Claude ║         2 ║ TimeStamp          ║
║  5 ║ John   ║         2 ║ TimeStamp          ║
╚════╩════════╩═══════════╩════════════════════╝
```

Code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.

class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #additional fields
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    wallet_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Player.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.player.save()


class Challenge(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    duration = models.DurationField()
    started_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class PlayerChallenge(models.Model):
    user_challenge_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    challenge = models.ForeignKey(Challenge, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    accepted_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user_challenge_id) + " (Player: " + str(self.player.user.username) + ", Challenge: " + str(self.challenge.id) + ")"
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from challengeview.models import Player,Challenge,PlayerChallenge

@login_required
def index(request):

    challenges = Challenge.objects.filter(playerchallenge__player = request.user.player)
    challenges_participants = Player.objects.filter(playerchallenge__challenge = challenges)

    my_dict = {
     'challenges_participants' : challenges_participants,
     'challenges' : challenges,

    }
    return render(request, "challengeview/index.html", context=my_dict)
```

Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to change view only or model structure as well?

Comment: Ideally I want to only adapt the filtering in views.py. However, if adaptions in models.py are required I am ofc also interested in your approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Django, you cannot model relations as in the simple **SQL** tables. There 3 powerful relationship types `OnetoOne, ForeignKey, ManytoMany`.
    from django.utils import timezone

```
class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #additional fields
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    wallet_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    challenges = models.ManyToMany('Challenge') #a challenge can be belonged to many players in this case
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Player.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.player.save()


class Challenge(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    duration = models.DurationField()
    started_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class PlayerActivity(models.Model):
    challenge = models.ForeingKey(on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                   null=True,
                                 related_name='activity_challenge')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Player,
                                   on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                   null=True,
                                 related_name='activity_created_by')

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user_challenge_id) + " (Player: " + str(self.player.user.username) + ", Challenge: " + str(self.challenge.id) + ")"
```

If a Challenge can belong to only one player but a player can have many challenges then **Foreignkey**. If a player can have many challenges and a challenge can belong to many players then  **ManyToMany**.

When you use queries you should always think of request sent to the backend. You can use `select_related` to minimize the request.

```
all_challenges = Challenge.objects.all()
logged_user_challenges = Player.objects.filter(user=request.user,challenges__in=all_challenges)
others_same_challenges = Player.objects.filter(challenges=logged_user_challenges.challenges)
```

**OR**

```
logged_user_challenges = PlayerActivity.objects.filter(user=request.user).latest('created_at')
```

But you will have an issue with others_... You will need a loop to get all and this is just not adviced.

Note: You have to manipulate data savings in views.

Comment: Hi Rarblack. Thanks for your help. So the relationship between challenges and player is the following:
- one player can participate in multiple challenges
- one challenge can have multiple players as participants
- There are specific fields (e.g. timestamp when a player accepted a challenge), that are unique and a 1-to-1 relationship. In used the PlayerChallenge model to show this relationship. So my goal is to have a list of challenges for the logged_in player and also show all other players that are participating in the same challenge. Are my current models are suitable for this?

Comment: If yes, how to write the query? If no, how should I adapt my 3 models to make this work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Okay, now it is more clear. I have already fixed your issues. You don't need the 3rd model instead you are using ManyToMany relationship. You can use player__in in filter part to filter players.

Comment: Ok, thx. But without the third model, where do I store the specific parameters (e.g. accepted_timestamp) that are needed for each combination of player and challenge?

Comment: Thanks for your iteration. There is one thing that I do not understand: I see that you added the parameter challenge in the Player model. However, how do I reflect the fact that one player can participate in multiple challenges? Would I just create a player instance per player/challenge combination where the player information (e.g. wallet_balance) is duplicated? Also in the queries: is the others_same_challenges not supposed to use the PlayerActivity model? Thx!

Comment: The relation is like Book and its Genre. You should since Genre is independent, storing players in that will be confusing in the long run. So you should store them in the player model or in a totally new model which will play a joint role. PlayerActivity is just playing a logger model so, you can also get the latest date record from there for either a single user or all. As I said it is up to how your view is desinged.

Comment: I did not fully understand your last comment. I edited my original question and added example data to explain what I am looking to do. Does this help for understanding? Is there a way to do this by keeping my three models Player, Challenge and PlayerChallenge? Thx!